# Deleting the rows of a table based on the id starting with some value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using clone method to create the rows dynamically. While creating the rows, I have assigned the id field for the rows in the form of cloneObject111, cloneObject1110, cloneObject1111 and cloneObject1112, each time.

Where id=cloneObject111 indicates the parent row and rest all are its children. 
So when we click on the clone button for the second time, id fields will be starting from cloneObject222 and so on.

Here the problem is, when I click on the delete button which is assigned for only the parent row(with id=cloneObject111), I am calling a function to delete the parent row as well as its children.

Following is my screen for better understanding.

[image: cloneImage]

On click of "-" sign in the above image, I am calling the function removeChildRows(rowId) to delete the last 4 rows but it did not work, please help me to write this complete javascript function. Thanks in advance.

```
function removeChildRows(r){
    console.log("Delete the Child Rows based on their Index"+r);

    row=document.getElementById("tr[id^=cloneObject" + r +"]");
    console.log(row);

}
```

Comment: Where it is said, that `getElementById` takes a selector as an argument? Use `querySelector` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somehow I made it to work with the following code. Hope it may help someone.

```
function removeChildRows(r){
    console.log("Delete the Child Rows based on their Index"+r);

    $("tr[id^=cloneObject" + r +"]").each(function(){

        $(this).closest("tr").remove();

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a attribute values starts with selector, which will not work with `document.getElementById()` as the method name is self explanatory .

create a valid id using string concatenation and then use

```
row = document.getElementById("cloneObject" + r);
```

OR, Use `querySelector()`/`querySelectorAll()`

```
row=document.querySelector("tr[id^=cloneObject" + r +"]");
```

---

To remove just call the `remove()` method

```
row.remove()
```

Comment: I made it to work :-) And I will try with your answer as well. Thanks for the answer. :-)